# Como implementar imagelightbox

Tags: lightbox

Estou tentando implementar lightbox em um site de uma página que gostei, só que não entendi muito bem onde e como aplicar os estilos que são apresentados na página: http://osvaldas.info/examples/image-lightbox-responsive-touch-friendly/
Até tem uma página que explica como proceder no próprio site, mas está meio confuso pra mim.
Copiei o arquivo imagelightbox.js, chamei na index e copiei o código que faz a chamada para o lightbox.

```
$( function()
{
    $( '.dout' ).imageLightbox();
});
```

O estilo mínimo exigido do css também coloquei:

```
#imagelightbox{ 
position: fixed;
z-index: 9999; 
-ms-touch-action: none;
touch-action: none;}
```

O html está assim:

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="dout" href="../images/reformas-renascer-obra1.jpg" data-imagelightbox="g"><img width="150" height="150" src="../images/reformas-renascer-obra1.jpg" id="imagelightbox" /></a>
    <a class="dout" href="../images/reformas-renascer-obra2.jpg" data-imagelightbox="g"><img width="150" height="150" src="../images/reformas-renascer-obra2.jpg" id="imagelightbox" /></a>
    <a class="dout" href="../images/reformas-renascer-obra3.jpg" data-imagelightbox="g"><img width="150" height="150" src="../images/reformas-renascer-obra3.jpg" id="imagelightbox" /></a>
    <a class="dout" href="../images/reformas-renascer-obra4.jpg" data-imagelightbox="g"><img width="150" height="150" src="../images/reformas-renascer-obra4.jpg" id="imagelightbox" /></a>
    <a class="dout" href="../images/reformas-renascer-obra5.jpg" data-imagelightbox="g"><img width="150" height="150" src="../images/reformas-renascer-obra5.jpg" id="imagelightbox" /></a>
</div>
```

Está tudo funcionando no exemplo que fiz aqui http://186.250.243.138/~reformas/galeria/.
O problema é que não estou conseguindo copiar as opções que mostra na página do primeiro link